# Java Syntax flaw

Tags: java, windows

**Why is NetBeans not showing the error warning for the following code ? I thogught that the "while" statement required brackets.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
int x;
int y = 0;

Scanner input;
input = new Scanner(System.in);
x= input.nextInt();
    do {
y=y+1;

if  (y == 0){
    System.out.println("Eroare");
}while (x == 0 )

if  (y == 0){
    System.out.println("Eroare");
}while (x == 1 )

 if (x%y == 0){
    System.out.println (y);
}

}while (y<x);


}
```

Comment: not a error but it will act as endless loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` statement does not require brackets, nor do `if`, `else`, etc.

The following snippet

```
if (foo) {
    bar;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if (foo)
    bar;
```

Here's your same code, cleaned up a bit (changing only whitespace) so that you can see what's going on:

```
Scanner input;
input = new Scanner(System.in);
x = input.nextInt();
do {
    y = y + 1;
    if (y == 0){
        System.out.println("Eroare");
    }
    while (x == 0)
        if (y == 0){
            System.out.println("Eroare");
        }
    while (x == 1)
        if (x%y == 0){
            System.out.println (y);
        }
} while (y < x);
```

Answer (score 2):

No. The while statement can use a single line statement as well.

```
while (true) ; // <-- infinite loop. Empty block consisting of a semi-colon.
```

Answer (score 0):

While statements can be used without bracers as,

`while(condition)`
    `Stmt;`